# SSL error connecting my own OpenShift PaaS Server

Tags: openshift-origin

I configured a OpenShift installation in CentOS 6.3 using the follow tutorial: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/wiki/build-your-own

All services are OK, up and running.

However, when I try to connect my rhc client to my server (running the follow commands), a SSL error appears. Appears that i've to trust my Self-Signed SSL Certificate. I'm using OS X, so I added the .cer file to keychain. This made acessing the https URL from Safari appears OK, however the rhc command's still with error.

```
Mac-de-Ariel:~ ariel$ export LIBRA_SERVER=MY_DOMAIN
Mac-de-Ariel:~ ariel$ rhc server 
/Users/ariel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: (null) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Full error: https://gist.github.com/0e9019f39c59512eb54b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'rhc server' doesn't work against Origin servers yet - right now it only works against openshift.redhat.com.  I would recommend trying:

```
LIBRA_SERVER=yourhost rhc setup
```

Setup will run against your provided server and do the necessary config, and then save the server variable into the ~/.openshift/express.conf file for future use.